# Watir Display Content from a table in a text file

Tags: ruby, watir

I am using watir-webdriver, I am trying to write the content displayed in a table below (RATE CODE SELECTED NOT AVAILABLE THIS LOCATION OR CAR 138DE) into a text file but I can't get it to display the content. Any idea what i doing wrong ? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
errorMes = browser.select_list(:name => 'seamlessMessages').value
    f3=File.open( 'Error Log - Conf Res.txt', 'a') 
    f3.puts "Cancel Reservation - FAILED - Res ID: " +tasid+" - " + CSAsite + " - Message: " +errorMes
    f3.puts "\n"
    f3.close
```

code

```
<TD><B>Error/Informational&nbsp;Messages</B></TD>
                <TD><B>Number&nbsp;of&nbsp;Messages</B></TD>
                <TD class="tableData"><span name="nbrOfMessages"/>1</span></TD>
                <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD height="1"></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <TABLE width="100%" class="displaySubsection" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <TR>
                <TD width="5" rowspan="3"></TD>
                <TD width="800"></TD>
                <TD width="5" rowspan="3"></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <select name="seamlessMessages" size="2" readonly tabIndex="-1" class="readonly wide"><option value="0" selected>RATE CODE SELECTED NOT AVAILABLE THIS LOCATION OR CAR     138DE     </option></select>
                </TD>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't get it to display the content"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that you are getting "0" instead of "RATE CODE SELECTED NOT AVAILABLE THIS LOCATION OR CAR 138DE".

When you do `errorMes = browser.select_list(:name => 'seamlessMessages').value`, it is returning the 'value' attribute of the selected option.

If you want the text, you need to do:

```
errorMes = browser.select_list(:name => 'seamlessMessages').selected_options.first.text
```

Comment: Note that this solution works for Watir 3.0.0, which has `selected_options` returning an array of Option elements. If using Watir 1.6.5, `selected_options` returns an array of string values and therefore does not need the `.text` (as seen in Sal's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right I was getting "0"

Just to let you know that when i tried

```
errorMes = browser.select_list(:name => 'seamlessMessages').selected_options.first.text
```

I got an error message in `<main>': undefined method`text' for "RATE CODE SELECTED
 NOT AVAILABLE THIS LOCATION OR CAR 138DE":String (NoMethodError)

By removing .text it did work. Thanks a lot for your help on this.

```
errorMes = browser.select_list(:name => 'seamlessMessages').selected_options.first
```